# React Apollo - how to refetch (update) data after nodejs graphql backend returned async response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo

The situation is simple.

I have NodeJS GraphQL backend with users data. When new user is added I can refetch this updated users data with React Apollo without a problem. But then I added async operation to my backend - when I add a new user with GraphQL I fetch data from external source to populate some information about the user. Everything works except refetch, because (I assume) refetch is triggered before async operation is finished. When I put a button to manually refetch, everything works.

My code is this:

```
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";

const [addUser, { error }] = useMutation(ADD_USER_MUTATION);

addUser({
  variables: {
    name: John Doe,
  },
}).then(() => props.refetch());
```

Is there a way in React/Apollo that I know when graphql async operation is finished on the server?

Comment: [a]wait before return mutation response

Comment: I did that, of course... It is not working.

Comment: show mutation resolver code, of course

Answer (score 0):

You can use refetchQueries method inside your mutation parameters:

```
addUser({
  variables: {
    name: 'John Doe',
  },
  refetchQueries: [
    {
      query: YOUR_QUERY,
      ...otherQueryOptions,
    },
  ]
});
```

Docs for the hook:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usemutation

But before using this, you have to be sure that the data you want to get cannot be got from client. (In your example, you can get the name of the user from client, because you already have the name state).

In your situation, I would use optimisticResponse and cache for better performance.

Optimistic UI:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/optimistic-ui/#gatsby-focus-wrapper